# Log4J 2 shutdown behaviour, keeps log handle open in some apps

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to shutdown Log4J once my EJB application stops, as described here: 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#shutdown

For some apps it works perfectly, the log file handle is released. But for others it does not, and file is still open after application is stopped, while usage of loggers is just the same. 
What can I try to check to fix that?

Log4J version is the latest, 2.5.

Comment: Are your applications web apps?  If so, what ServletContextListeners do they have, if any?

Comment: No, in fact applications are EJB, no webapps at all.

Comment: I recommend raising this on the log4j2 issue tracker and try to get the log4j2 team to look at this.